# wordpress make a wizard to collect information from user and save it in a database

Tags: html, database, wordpress, web, elementor

I am attempting to make a step through wizard in word press. I have a website with a nice theme and everything and all pages work fine. What i want to do is in one of the page collect some information from the customer. When they select one of the buttons on the site i want them to end up on a page that has a bunch of options. Based on their selection i want a certain information captured and then the wizard moves to the next page.

Step by step i want to collect 5 or 6 pieces of information that the user selects. Kind of like a wizard that the user can select their options and that gets saved to their profile. Now i am not exactly sure how database management works in word press, how i can create rows or columns based on what i need and how i can save information to these. All the word press tutorials that i find are basic and dont show this type of behavior and data manipulation. Can someone point me in the right direction where i can learn about how to set up databases and collect information from the user?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data for user you can first create User Meta Fields. You can follow this link on how to create User meta fields 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/ . You can then save the data from the form in this meta fields using update_user_meta()
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/. You can fetch this data using function get_user_meta()
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

I hope this helps you !!